# macro under linux - Nyikodem

Tags: linux, centos, macros

How can I write a macro under linux?
The system is Centos 6.x on an Intel server. I use this linux from remote via Teraterm. 
There is a character based program on the server let us called "PP". I would like to write a macro that drives PP. This macro has to 
- start PP
- sends key hits like up, down, enter, F3, and characters to PP
- and I would like to manipulate files on the server meanwhile the operation runs as well

I tried to use cpability of Teraterm, but it runs on windows PC remotely and I could not manipulate files on the server meanwhile.

How can I do it? Is there any language which can be used? Macro recording with editing of recorded macro? Is there a solution already progrmmed with an IDE?

Thank you in advance.

Nyikodem

Comment: Do you really want that? There aere plenty of ways to manipulate files on a remote machine using a GUI on your local (if you connect via SSH, you can use any SFTP client). Otherwise TeraTerm itself does macros it seems.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I would like to write a script which starts a program. then the script controls the program like typing username then presses tab then typing password then types enter and so on...